# Restangular PUT attaches _id two times for no reason

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Iam using Restangular on the clientside with _id as Id field. Sadly Restangular generates wrong URLs, maybe you could say me where the error is?

```
Restangular.all('/users').one(id).get().then(functon(results) {
    $scope.data = results;
})
```

After the user edited the data:

```
$scope.save = function() {
     $scope.data.put().then(...);
};
```

This very simple sample generates the following URL with the id twice. I have no idea what went wrong. :(

**PUT /users/537283783b17a7fab6e49f66/537283783b17a7fab6e49f66**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by changing the Request workflow of Restangular.

I don't now why, but this approad **does not work**:

```
Restangular.all('/users').one(id).get() ... result.put();
```

But this does:

```
Restangular.one('/users/',id).get() ... result.put();
```

Also it is important to tell Restangular that you were using _id instead of id:

```
angular.module('App').config(function(RestangularProvider, AppSettings) {
  RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({id: "_id"});
});
```